# VS2008 not working with SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I've both VS2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express installed in my computer. When I try create a new DB or attach an existing one, I get the following error message:"**This version of server is not supported - Only versions up to 2005 are supported.**"

From that, I'd like to know:

- Is it possible that VS2008 with SP1 be not able to support SQL Server 2008 Express?
- In case that's possible what can i do? Is it possible to update or should I install an other version?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue you need service pack 1:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

Jay's link is for 2005

Comment: I'm glad someone's paying attention to what I'm doing.  Thanks.